# How to change the install type in android studio from standard to custom?

Tags: android-studio

I have mistakenly installed the standard type of android studio but I want to change it to the custom type of android studio. I have installed the android studio two times again but it is not showing these options, it is directly using the standard install type. So how can I change it??

Comment: Are you asking about the stable and preview version of the android studio?  Eg.Stable-Artic fox, beta-bumble bee, canary-chipmunk.

Answer (score 0):

Desinstall Android Studio

After that, delete every folder with Android things.

Like C:\Program Files\Android

And all non-visible-folder like C:\Users\YOUR-USER-HERE\AppData\Local\Google